# MySQL select between 2 dates (timestamps stored as INT)

Tags: mysql

I have this record in the `sales` table:

`time`: 1487884981 (INT), `amount`: 10

When running this query, I get NULL.

```
SELECT SUM(`amount`)
FROM `sales`
WHERE `time`
BETWEEN DATE_SUB(1488949200, INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND 1488949200;
```

What should I modify to get the desired result 10?

Note to clarify: the query should return the sum of all records that are in between (1488949200 - 30 DAYS) and 1488949200, and in this case it should return 10 because the record's timestamp is in between those 2 different dates.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [FROM_UNIXTIME()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) to convert seconds since the epoch to actual dates:

```
SELECT SUM(amount)
FROM sales
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(time) BETWEEN
      DATE_SUB(FROM_UNIXTIME(1488949200), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND
      FROM_UNIXTIME(1488949200);
```

Comment: I still get NULL result when using this.

Comment: Look at the bounds in the range in your original query...both are the same, and your data point is outside those bounds.

Comment: Both are the same because it's a 30 day interval  between (DATE - 30 days) and DATE, the record's `time` is actually in-between that.

Comment: Practically, I do not know the time of the record in MySQL, that's why my intention is to query it with a 30 day date interval.

Comment: @DanP. Careless mistake...we also need to wrap the `time` column using `FROM_UNIXTIME()` to use it as a date.